# Julia 1.0 - using Querverse

Tags: package, julia, ijulia-notebook

I'm trying to load **queryverse** and it fails. Is anyone else facing the same?  Any suggestions? Can someone help me fix this?

Please follow the hyperlink (error - output) to view the error message! Thanks.

PFA.  [error - ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJbb9.png)

Comment: I get the same error. Queryverse seems to be very young. As Julia 1.0 is very young itself, chances are high that you will see errors. Best thing would be to wait for both to stabilize.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my laptop and did the following commands and it eventually worked. Basically what I think happened at least for me was I had an older version of Julia installed and think that these packages just didn't get compiled for the current version of Julia.. but I don't really know its all magic but this might be worth a try.

```
Pkg.add("VegaDatasets")
Pkg.build("PyCall")
Pkg.add("VegaLite")
Pkg.build("NodeJS")
Pkg.build("VegaLite")
```